# Match Bayesian Networks using Joint Probablity to Network Graph

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayesian-networks, probability-theory

I'm stuck on a task right now. Given the Joint Probabilities given below, how can I show that they belong exactly to one of the networks (and not to the other two). According to my intuition I would have guessed Network 3, but how do I show that?

Thanks a lot in advance.
[image: Joint Probability and Networks]

Answer (score 1):

1. P(A,B)!=P(A)*P(B). Network III d-separates A and B => it cannot be the good one
2. P(A,B|C)!=P(A|C)*P(B|C). Network I d-sepaates A and B given C => it cannot be the good one

So the good one should be Network II.

[image]